# Remove WordPress Login Animation

Tags: login

So with WordPress if you fail a Login the screen refreshes and when it does the Login Form does this shake animation which I don't really like I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of this?

I'm grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove the shake -- at least that's what [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+remove+login+shake) says.

```
function wpb_remove_loginshake() {
    remove_action('login_head', 'wp_shake_js', 12);
}
add_action('login_head', 'wpb_remove_loginshake');
```